# Drupal 7 Commerce - How would you increase or decrease a checkout total price depending on payment type?

Tags: 7, commerce

I want to be able to provide alternative payment methods during checkout, but I also want to be able to discount or add on top of the total checkout price by a percentage depending on what the user chooses to pay with. How can this be done? I know you would use rules, but which sections would i need to edit?

** edit - I was able to edit up the the "pricing rules" page, but now i get an error for Order Total. I want to be able to mutltiply the order total as seen below. I'm not sure what to put after the colon : of order total.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the checkout methods rules you should be able to add an action that decreases the total or subtotal cost.  So when a certain payment method is used, the subtotal will decrease.

If one of those rules actions isn't available you might need to look at some other modules like [Commerce Rules Extra](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra).

Another option would be to apply coupons automatically to orders with those selected payment methods with the [Commerce Coupon](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) and [Commerce Coupon Fixed Amount](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon_fixed_amount) modules.  That might give you better control over how many times a user or how many users can use a discount like this.

Answer (score 0):

With [Commerce Fees](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees), you can add fees to a order, use the event and action that the module provides.